# Is it possible to create a custom asset browser menu and a custom inner asset browser window?

Tags: asset-browser

I want to create a custom asset browser with additional custom features.
How can set custom asset browser menu like (in Data -> File Browser, Asset Browser, Spreadsheet, etc...) and on click that menu opens like existing asset browser(but here I also want a custom panel, operators....).[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello! Short answer is the only way to do it currently is to modify the source code.

Comment: Please guide that how can i do that?

Comment: Do you know how to code in C / C++ ?

Comment: No, I don't. But I know python.